Datagridview Image Column - Retrieve Image Path
I have a datagridview that has a column for an Image. The user can choose an image file from their local computer and add it to the datagridview.
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(pictureBox_AbilityInfo_Icon.ImageLocation);

Once the user is finished adding information to the datagridview, I am saving the contents of each cell so that I can load it again later.
When saving the value of Image column I am using the following code:
 doc.Element("AbilityInformation").Element(abilityName).Add(new XAttribute("Icon", form_MainUI.dataGridView_AbilityInfo_ClassAbllityInformation.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));

However, this saves as the following: Icon="System.Drawing.Bitmap"
I WANT to save the image's local path so that I can load the picture again when I load the saved information.
How do I get a datagridviewimagecolumn image path?

Use the cell Tag property to keep the image path.

If you want the path you need to save it as it is not contained in the image. you may want to consider saving only the path but that would rely on it being valid across users..

dr.null was correct. I needed to add the path to the cell's Tag.
pictureBox_AbilityInfo_Icon.Tag = Path;

